# Javascript: Is my variable NaN or is it a Number?

Tags: javascript, nan

I'm not able to establish if my javascript variable is a number or not.

Here's what I have:

```
alert('variable startDateB: ' + startDateB);
```

Results:

```
variable startDateB: NaN
```

In the very next line I have:

```
alert('typeof startDateB: '  + typeof(startDateB));
```

Results:

```
typeof startDateB: number
```

My end goal is to compare this date with other dates, but I don't know whether a conversion is necessary since I appear to be getting mixed information about the variable's data type.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The special value `NaN` **is** a number.

Comment: `console.log(typeof NaN)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, `NaN` is the return value from operations which have an *undefined* numerical result.

Aside from being part of the global object, it is also part of the `Number` object: `Number.NaN`.

This is why you are seeing the behavior you describe.  `NaN` is part of the `Number` object.

It is still a numeric data type, but it is undefined as a real number.